# How to flatten a deeply and irregularly nested list/JSON in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe, nested

I'm trying to flatten a deeply/irregularly nested list/JSON object to a dataframe in R.

The key names are consistent, but the number of nested elements differ from one element to the next.

I've tried flattening the list using `jsonlite` and the `tidyr::unnest` function, but `tidyr::unnest` isn't able to unnest a list-column that contains multiple new columns. I've also tried using the `map` functions in the `purrr` package, but can't get anything to work.

A subset of the JSON data is below, and a list object is included at the end of this post.

```
[
  {
    "name": ["Hillary Clinton"],
    "type": ["PERSON"],
    "metadata": {
      "mid": ["/m/0d06m5"],
      "wikipedia_url": ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton"]
    },
    "salience": [0.2883],
    "mentions": [
      {
        "text": {
          "content": ["Clinton"],
          "beginOffset": [132]
        },
        "type": ["PROPER"]
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "content": ["Mrs."],
          "beginOffset": [127]
        },
        "type": ["COMMON"]
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "content": ["Clinton"],
          "beginOffset": [403]
        },
        "type": ["PROPER"]
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "content": ["Mrs."],
          "beginOffset": [398]
        },
        "type": ["COMMON"]
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "content": ["Hillary Clinton"],
          "beginOffset": [430]
        },
        "type": ["PROPER"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": ["Trump"],
    "type": ["PERSON"],
    "metadata": {
      "mid": ["/m/0cqt90"],
      "wikipedia_url": ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump"]
    },
    "salience": [0.245],
    "mentions": [
      {
        "text": {
          "content": ["Trump"],
          "beginOffset": [24]
        },
        "type": ["PROPER"]
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "content": ["Mr."],
          "beginOffset": [20]
        },
        "type": ["COMMON"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the desired output would be a dataframe like the one below, where the outer elements are repeated and each of the inner-most element have their own rows.

```
name                type        metadata.mid    metadata.wikipedia_url                          salience    mentions.text.content   mentions.text.beginOffset   mentions.type
Hillary Clinton     PERSON      /m/0d06m5       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton    0.2883      Clinton                 132                         PROPER
Hillary Clinton     PERSON      /m/0d06m5       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton    0.2883      Mrs.                    127                         COMMON
Hillary Clinton     PERSON      /m/0d06m5       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton    0.2883      Clinton                 403                         PROPER
Hillary Clinton     PERSON      /m/0d06m5       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton    0.2883      Mrs.                    398                         COMMON
Hillary Clinton     PERSON      /m/0d06m5       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton    0.2883      Hillary Clinton         430                         PROPER
Trump               PERSON      /m/0cqt90       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump       0.245       Trump                   24                          PROPER
Trump               PERSON      /m/0cqt90       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump       0.245       Mr.                     20                          COMMON
```

Is there a general/scalable way to flatten this type of data?

---

An R list object:

```
nested_list <- list(structure(list(name = "Hillary Clinton", type = "PERSON", 
    metadata = structure(list(mid = "/m/0d06m5", wikipedia_url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton"), .Names = c("mid", 
    "wikipedia_url")), salience = 0.28831193, mentions = list(
        structure(list(text = structure(list(content = "Clinton", 
            beginOffset = 132L), .Names = c("content", "beginOffset"
        )), type = "PROPER"), .Names = c("text", "type")), structure(list(
            text = structure(list(content = "Mrs.", beginOffset = 127L), .Names = c("content", 
            "beginOffset")), type = "COMMON"), .Names = c("text", 
        "type")), structure(list(text = structure(list(content = "Clinton", 
            beginOffset = 403L), .Names = c("content", "beginOffset"
        )), type = "PROPER"), .Names = c("text", "type")), structure(list(
            text = structure(list(content = "Mrs.", beginOffset = 398L), .Names = c("content", 
            "beginOffset")), type = "COMMON"), .Names = c("text", 
        "type")), structure(list(text = structure(list(content = "Hillary Clinton", 
            beginOffset = 430L), .Names = c("content", "beginOffset"
        )), type = "PROPER"), .Names = c("text", "type")))), .Names = c("name", 
"type", "metadata", "salience", "mentions")), structure(list(
    name = "Trump", type = "PERSON", metadata = structure(list(
        mid = "/m/0cqt90", wikipedia_url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump"), .Names = c("mid", 
    "wikipedia_url")), salience = 0.24501903, mentions = list(
        structure(list(text = structure(list(content = "Trump", 
            beginOffset = 24L), .Names = c("content", "beginOffset"
        )), type = "PROPER"), .Names = c("text", "type")), structure(list(
            text = structure(list(content = "Mr.", beginOffset = 20L), .Names = c("content", 
            "beginOffset")), type = "COMMON"), .Names = c("text", 
        "type")))), .Names = c("name", "type", "metadata", "salience", 
"mentions")))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach:

```
map_df(nested_list, function(x) {

  df <- flatten_df(x[c("name", "type", "metadata", "salience")]) 

  map_df(x$mentions, ~c(as.list(.$text), mentions_type=.$type)) %>%
    mutate(name=df$name, type=df$type, mid=df$mid,
           wikipedia_url=df$wikipedia_url, salience=df$salience)

}) %>% glimpse()
## Observations: 7
## Variables: 8
## $ content       <chr> "Clinton", "Mrs.", "Clinton", "Mrs.", "Hillary Clinton", "Trump", "Mr."
## $ beginOffset   <int> 132, 127, 403, 398, 430, 24, 20
## $ mentions_type <chr> "PROPER", "COMMON", "PROPER", "COMMON", "PROPER", "PROPER", "COMMON"
## $ name          <chr> "Hillary Clinton", "Hillary Clinton", "Hillary Clinton", "Hillary Clinton", "Hillary Clinton", "Trump", "Trump"
## $ type          <chr> "PERSON", "PERSON", "PERSON", "PERSON", "PERSON", "PERSON", "PERSON"
## $ mid           <chr> "/m/0d06m5", "/m/0d06m5", "/m/0d06m5", "/m/0d06m5", "/m/0d06m5", "/m/0cqt90", "/m/0cqt90"
## $ wikipedia_url <chr> "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton", "http://en.wikiped...
## $ salience      <dbl> 0.2883119, 0.2883119, 0.2883119, 0.2883119, 0.2883119, 0.2450190, 0.2450190
```

Comment: Thank you! To retrieve the `mentions>type` field, would I do something similar to the `map_df(x$mentions, ...` line? Alternatively, do you have any good resources for understanding how to use the `purrr::map*` functions?

Comment: Aye. Answer updated to add that field. I'm doing a presentation on `purrr` (more generally, piping) at rstudioconf in January, so I'll try to put a link here but you can watch for that on their site or http://rud.is/b sometime after January as well.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer has such a small number of upvotes. It's a well written and insightful answer to  a well-written question. Expanding JSON files must be a fairly common need these days. Link for purrr talk https://rud.is/b/2016/07/26/use-quick-formula-functions-in-purrrmap-base-vs-tidtyverse-idiom-comparisonsexamples/